# add a custom comment to product in shopping cart

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I need to add the option for users to add a comment against each product in the shopping cart in a similar way to how the wish list works so the comment will then be submitted in the sales confirmation email.

I’ve searched for a solution but can’t find anything compatible with 1.6.

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In simplest term what you can do is:
1> Create new tables(one for quote and another for order) with following fields:
quote_product_comments

```
id | quote_id | item_id | comment |
```

order_product_comments

```
id | order_id | item_id | comment |
```

2> Store the values in quote table during checkout
3> Hook into the event: checkout_type_onepage_save_order in order to transfer the quote data to order table.

Hope this helps you a bit.
Cheers!